# MySQL Select second count of pre selected results

Tags: php, mysql

Hello I am trying to make a Select where the uses chooses department and would like to have clause `WHERE` this department is first, let's say we select 10 results from department: Taxes and then make a `SUM` `SELECT` of fee `WHERE status = 1`. Which results be selected based on the first select All the results are coming from the same table.

```
| id | department | status | fee |
----------------------------------
| 1  | tax        |   1    | 20  |
| 2  | tax        |   2    | 20  |
| 3  | tax        |   1    | 20  |
| 4  | accounting |   1    | 20  |
```

So I would like to select if department is choose as tax, and status is 1 the sum of FEE columns  which should be 40

So far my Select query looks like this:

```
SELECT P.id, P.fee, (SELECT SUM(P.fee) FROM cases P WHERE status = 1) as fee_USD
FROM cases P WHERE 1";
if (!empty($department)) { $sql .= " AND P.department = '$department'"; }
```

the last line is checking if department is given as select option. there are other options as well but to make it simple I have pasted only this part of it. Any help is welcome.

In the Current Selection Fee is = 80

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add *correlation* to your query:

```sql
SELECT P1.id, P1.fee, 
      (SELECT SUM(P2.fee) 
       FROM cases P2 
       WHERE P2.department = P1.department AND status = 1) as fee_USD
FROM cases P1 
WHERE 1 ...
```

This way the subquery will return the `SUM` of only those records which are related to the current record of the main query.

Comment: This is vert good solution, One question is there a way to check in the WHERE clause first if the given $department is not null if it is null to remove this condition: P2.department = P1.department

Comment: @JohnSiniger Yes, normally we do something like `$department IS NULL OR department = $department`.